# Why do the page report errors when I use the for loop to traverse arrays in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Today, I try to write a web page that can receive users' data and display it to the user. Therefore, I use an array to store data and for loop to read data.
When I run the code, there is an error in line16(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined). I guess that I use the for-loop in the wrong way. If someone can figure out, Please notice me. Thanks！

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
        var students = [["2019001","like",89,92,91],["2019002","zhnagsan",67,89,77]];
        function load_data()
        {
        var table_result;
        table_result = "<table border=1>";
        table_result += "<tr><th>student number</th><th>student name</th><th>score1</th><th>score2</th><th>score3</th></tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) 
        {
            table_result += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < students[i].length; j++) 
            {
              table_result += "<td>"+students[i][j]+"</td>"
            }
            table_result += "</tr>";
        }
        table_result += "</table>";
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = table_result;
        }
        function add_new()
        {
        var studentName, studentNumber, score1, score2, score3;
        studentName = document.getElementById("studentName").value;
        studentNumber = document.getElementById("studentNumber").value;
        score1 = document.getElementById("score1").value;
        score2 = document.getElementById("score2").value;
        score3 = document.getElementById("score3").value;
        var addition;
        additon = new Array(studentNumber,studentName,score1,score2,score3);
        students.push(addition);
        load_data();
        }
</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load_data()">
        <div id="result">
        </div>
        <form>
            student name: <input type="text" id="studentName"><br>
            student number: <input type="text" id="studentNumber"><br>
            score1: <input type="text" id="score1"><br>
            score2: <input type="text" id="score2"><br>
            score3: <input type="text" id="score3"><br>
            <input type="button" id="button" onclick="add_new()" value="add"><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
        var students = [["2019001","like",89,92,91],["2019002","zhnagsan",67,89,77]];
        function load_data()
        {
        var table_result;
        table_result = "<table border=1>";
        table_result += "<tr><th>student number</th><th>student name</th><th>score1</th><th>score2</th><th>score3</th></tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) 
        {
            table_result += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < students[i].length; j++) 
            {
              table_result += "<td>"+students[i][j]+"</td>"
            }
            table_result += "</tr>";
        }
        table_result += "</table>";
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = table_result;
        }
        function add_new()
        {
        var studentName, studentNumber, score1, score2, score3;
        studentName = document.getElementById("studentName").value;
        studentNumber = document.getElementById("studentNumber").value;
        score1 = document.getElementById("score1").value;
        score2 = document.getElementById("score2").value;
        score3 = document.getElementById("score3").value;
        var addition;
        addition = new Array(studentNumber,studentName,score1,score2,score3);
        students.push(addition);
        load_data();
        }
</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load_data()">
        <div id="result">
        </div>
        <form>
            student name: <input type="text" id="studentName"><br>
            student number: <input type="text" id="studentNumber"><br>
            score1: <input type="text" id="score1"><br>
            score2: <input type="text" id="score2"><br>
            score3: <input type="text" id="score3"><br>
            <input type="button" id="button" onclick="add_new()" value="add"><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The only issue was a misspelling of `addition` on this line:

```js
additon = new Array(studentNumber,studentName,score1,score2,score3);
```